# How can I communicate mobile with PC browser?

Tags: google-chrome, bluetooth, websocket, wifi

I want to make an HTML5 game that can be controlled with mobile. So how to communicate between mobile and browser on PC?

I think of the following ways:

1. Bluetooth This may be the most easy way to use. But I searched and found that Chrome made bluetooth API proposal last year but is now available only on Chrome dev, which means I cannot make the game popular for everyone.
2. WiFi I don't know how to set up a host on browser using WiFi information. If so, I can then connect my mobile to WiFi. This is considered to be faster than web socket since it's local network.
3. Web Socket There're a lot of information about how to use this. But as this use WAN, it is considered to be slower and is my last choice.

So, does anyone know how to achieve this with the former 2 ways?